# google maps on JSP with Mysql db for coordinate

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I m very new to JSP. The application that I m working on has 4 parts

1. Android application that sends xml (geolocation data) to servlet.
2. Servlet stores that it in the database.(on the global IP)
3. The database is on the internal IP on the Lan.
4. Now JSP should take that data from the database (internal IP) and display on the google map.

So far the android application is sending the data to servlet and the servlet is putting that in DB now the problem is to take that data from DB (internal IP) and plot those coordinates on the Map.

IF this can be done in some other way changing the JSP to JS or some other framework then please suggest how.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet can send the data in JSON format. You can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for that. To plot the data, you can use the Google Maps JavaScript API. See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) example.